# How can I transform a row and make every 2 columns a new row while copying the first cell for each row?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this data in the following format:

```
ID   Product A   Product B
__________________________
1    19          27
2    12          32
```

But what I would like to have ii in this format:

```
ID   Product     Quantity
_________________________
1    Product A   19
1    Product B   27
2    Product A   12
2    Product B   32
```

Just a hint in the right direction could be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at Pivot tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mark mentioned, you need to use Pivot Tables.

[image]

Drag the ID to Row Fields and Each product to `Data Items` section.

[image]

Now move summation of values from column level to row level, because you want groups based on ids, not products, and the desired table is ready.

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! I set some design options, such as hide totals, repeat item labels and display as table, and it looks great. The only issue remaining is that I can't use the original column name 'Product A' as the value instead of 'Sum of Product A'.

Comment: @michiel You can actually rename them - just click on Values `dropdown list` - `Value Field Settings` - and provide the desired name under `Custom Name`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't choose 'Product A' as the name, Excel complains that the name is already used in the pivot table (I think because it's the name of the original column).